# Use tar to archive the contents of your home directory in linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to archive the contents of my home directory using tar and then compress the tar file with gzip. I know you can uncompress and unarchive the .tar.gz file using cat, tar and gzip. But , I don't know how to compress and archive.

Comment: Unpack: `tar xf foo.tar.gz`. Pack: `tar cfz foo.tar.gz ~/foo`.

Comment: To tar: tar -pcvzf tar-archive-name.tar.gz source-folder-name

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey there here is a link for your question. a full guide

https://www.howtogeek.com/248780/how-to-compress-and-extract-files-using-the-tar-command-on-linux/

```
tar -czvf name-of-archive.tar.gz /path/to/directory-or-file
```

Here’s what those switches actually mean:

```
-c: Create an archive.
-z: Compress the archive with gzip.
-v: Display progress in the terminal while creating the archive, also known as “verbose” mode. The v is always optional in these commands, but it’s helpful.
-f: Allows you to specify the filename of the archive.
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: I did. Twice. It consisted of a link to another site and a sentence fragment.

Comment: I did. Because you added actual information in your edit.

Comment: Take the time to post better answers. No one forces you to hit "Post Your Answer" prematurely. Read over what you've written.

Comment: @btl how my answer is link only answer? dude its the link to full guide and also it has the answer of explanation to the answer